# What is a Mega Backdoor Roth IRA?

Tags: united-states, 401k, ira, roth-ira, retirement-plan

The so-called "Mega Backdoor Roth IRA" was coined in the following article in 2014:

> I don’t hear about new ideas very often, but here is one that a few people might find very useful. I call it the **“Mega Backdoor Roth IRA.”**
>
> https://www.whitecoatinvestor.com/the-mega-backdoor-roth-ira/

401(k) plans normally have an annual contribution limit of **$19,000**.

Using the "Mega Backdoor" strategy, employees can seemingly attain an annual 401(k) contribution grand total of **$56,000** made up of pre-tax contributions, company match, *and after-tax contributions*.

Some of this 401(k) money can then be rolled into a Roth IRA, above and beyond the normal Roth IRA $6,000 annual contribution limit.

How does a Mega Backdoor Roth IRA work?

What 401(k) plan requirements are needed to enable this additional saving?

Answer (score 2):

The Mega Backdoor Roth IRA is achieved by contributing additional *after-tax* money to a 401(k), and then rolling those contributions into a Roth IRA.

Roth IRAs normally have an annual contribution limit of $6,000. Using a fully optimized Mega Backdoor Roth IRA allows **~$30,000+** of additional annual contributions to the Roth IRA.

---

#### Contributions Limits

401(k) plans have an annual pre-tax contribution limit of **$19,000** for the employee.

Employers then regularly contribute additional funds to the 401(k) via "company match".

The grand total for employee plus employer contributions is set at **$56,000** per year.

```
+ $19k (pre-tax  employee contributions)
+ $ X  (company match)
+ $ Y  (post-tax employee contributions) <- Mega Backdoor Roth IRA opportunity
  =======
  $56,000
```

The remainder of $56,000 minus pre-tax contributions and company match represents the Mega Backdoor Roth IRA opportunity.

---

#### 401(k) Plan Requirements

Only certain 401(k) plans will qualify for the Mega Backdoor Roth IRA, as it requires two somewhat rare features:

- Allow *post-tax contributions* to the 401(k), above the $19,000 pre-tax limit.
- Allow *in-service, non-hardship* withdrawls of that post-tax money, to be rolled into a Roth IRA.

---

#### Workflow

If these two plan requirements are met, employees can set their payroll system to automatically contribute post-tax money to their 401(k) with each paycheck.

The employee should then regularly make *in service, non-hardship* withdrawls of that recently-contributed money, sending it directly from the 401(k) to their Roth IRA plan administrator.

At the end of the year, all post-tax contributions from the 401(k) will have been rolled into the Roth IRA. This represents a substantial increase in Roth IRA contributions over the normal annual maximum of $6,000.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that there are also Roth 401(k) contributions, which are also under the $19k limit.

Comment: The requirements section is somewhat incomplete... as an alternative to *in-service, non-hardship withdrawls of that post-tax*, there is also a possibility of *in-plan conversion of post-tax contributions to Roth*, although strictly speaking while that is a Mega Backdoor Roth loophole, it is not a Mega Backdoor Roth *IRA*

Comment: @BenVoigt good info. A separate answer for that strategy would be very welcome here.